# how to show negative value in tooltip using highcharts pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I go through this example http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/XLepu/16/ for showing the negative value in pie chart or in tooltip and I tried it but it doesn't
below is my code.

javascript code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Pie1.aspx/FruitAnalysis",
                    //url: "WebService1.asmx/FruitAnalysis",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (Result) {
                        Result = Result.d;
                        var data = [];
                        for (var i in Result) {
                            //var serie = new Array(Result[i].Names, Result[i].Values, Result[i].Dummy);
                            var serie = new Array(Result[i].Names, Result[i].Values);
                            data.push(serie);
                        }
                        DreawChart(data);

                        $(".highcharts-credits")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        $(".highcharts-button-symbol").hide();
                    },
                    error: function (Result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            });

            function DreawChart(series) {

                $('#container').highcharts({

                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'fruit  market shares at a specific month, 2014'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        //pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                        //pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.int:}</b>'

                        formatter: function () {

                            var val = this.point.positive ? this.y : this.y * (-1);
                            //var val = this.y * (1);
                            //var val = this.y;

                            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + val;  //+ ' %'
                        }

                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                //format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                //format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} % : {point.name1}</b>',
                                //format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.int:}',

                                //formatter: function () {
                                //    return this.point.positive ? this.y : this.y * (-1);
                                //},

                                style: {
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        //name1: 'Dummy',
                        name: 'Fruit share',
                        data: series

                        //data: [
                        //    { name: 'Safari', y: 20, positive: true },
                        //    { name: 'Others', y: 50, positive: true },
                        //    { name: 'Opera', y: 30, positive: false }
                        //]
                    }]
                });
            }

        </script>
```

in the above  example : `series : [{data: series}]` I tried different ways but and not worked.

and .cs code is :

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static List<FruitEnity1> FruitAnalysis()
        {
            List<FruitEnity1> fruitinfo = new List<FruitEnity1>();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select name,value from tbl_fruitanalysis";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds, "FruitAnalysis");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ds == null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables["FruitAnalysis"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["FruitAnalysis"].Rows)
                        {
                            fruitinfo.Add(new FruitEnity1
                            {
                                Names = dr["name"].ToString(),
                                Values = Convert.ToInt32(dr["value"]),
                                //Dummy="A"
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fruitinfo.Add(new FruitEnity1
                {
                    Names = "Jan",
                    Values = Convert.ToInt32(1),
                    //Dummy = "-"
                });

                fruitinfo.Add(new FruitEnity1
                {
                    Names = "Feb",
                    Values = Convert.ToInt32(2),
                    //Dummy = "-"
                });

                fruitinfo.Add(new FruitEnity1
                {
                    Names = "Feb",
                    Values = Convert.ToInt32(-3),
                    //Dummy = "-"
                });
            }
            return fruitinfo;
        }
```

In the above code the `else` part code will execute and here we have a -ve vale (-3)

Class name is :

```
  public class FruitEnity1
    {
        public string Names { get; set; }
        public int Values { get; set; }
        //public string Dummy { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm new to this kind of piechats implementation work.

Give me your best suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: I see a few things. First, no idea why you are doing a `Convert.ToInt32()` when the value you are providing is already an int. Second, you are not passing back the `positive` field in C# that is required by the JavaScript `this.point.positive` property in your code.

Comment: @KScandrett, thanks for your comment and I did what you mentioned points in my coding part but still the negative values are not showing in the piechart the main agenda of is we should show the negative values dynamically from .cs page to .aspx(ajax call) if you have any good example please share it to me it will help a lot.

Comment: Hi @ashok, Please check and provide me with a value of the `Result` variable from the `success` JS callback function.

Comment: Also, you can't pass negative values to the pie chart: `Values = Convert.ToInt32(-3)`; that's why the example uses the `point.positive` property. You should be passing `Values = 3; Positive = false;` instead

Comment: @KScandrett, thanks for your comment and your solution is perfectly working to me (I'm able to fetching the +ve and -ne values)